# Polynomial regression multicollinearity assumption?

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn, multicollinearity, nonlinear-regression

The difference between `Linear regression` and `Polynomial regression` is that in the last we manipulate our original explanatory variables in a way to create polynomial dependency between `Y` and `X`. For the sake of simplicity if we consider one feature (explanatory variable) only: `X`, the `Polynomial regression` with degree `2` will look like this:

$Y$ = $\beta_0$ + $\beta_1\cdot X$ + $\beta_2\cdot X^2$

In `sklearn` we can do this by initializing and calling `fit_transform` method of `PolynomialFeatures(2)`. Eventually if we want to train our model we should use `LinearRegression` of `sklearn` to do so.

However, one of the assumptions of the `Linear Regression` is  that all features should be uncorrelated. $X$ and $X^2$, on the other hand are perfectly correlated. So, doesn't this create any issue with the training process?

Comment: There is no such assumption about uncorrelated predictors in linear regression. The Gauss-Markov theorem requires uncorrelated errors. Also, $X$ and $X^2$ are not perfectly correlated.

Comment: My post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/384636/919 illustrates and explains the possibilities for multicollinearity when introducing a quadratic term in a regression.  Additional insight can be had by searching our site for posts on orthogonal polynomials: the idea is that the *very same* model can be expressed in terms of two new variables $Z_1$ and $Z_2,$ derived as linear combinations of $X$ and $X^2,$ where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are centered and orthogonal: that is, there's no collinearity whatsoever.